# WP Rest API vs - how can I get author information from v2 - the author ID?

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest

I'm building a front end using WP JSON, and I need (among other things) the name of the author of each post.

In V1, this was easy - here's a fragment of a typical post object from calling http://example.com/wp-json/posts/1:

```
 {
    "ID": 1,
    "title": "Hello world!",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "author": {
        "ID": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "slug": "admin",
        "URL": "",
        "avatar": "http:\/\/0.gravatar.com\/avatar\/c57c8945079831fa3c19caef02e44614&d=404&r=G",
        "meta": {
            "links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/users\/1",
                "archives": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/users\/1\/posts"
            }
        }
    },
```

But in V2, for author, all we get back is the ID (an integer). Passing this back to the API, we get a list of every article an author has written - but how can I get the author's information - their name, avatar, etc.?

PS: boy the V2 documentation is sparse...V1 was much better...

Answer (score 37):

Append the query parameter _embed in your API URL

Embedding is triggered by setting the _embed query parameter on the request. This will then include embedded resources under the _embedded key adjacent to the _links key in JSON file... as showed in http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/links.html

Examples:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed

http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter%5Bposts_per_page%5D=10&page=1&_embed
```

Getting Author Name from JSON, and showing:

```
{{postItem._embedded.author[0].name}}
```

Getting Featured Image:

```
{{postItem._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url}}
```

Categories:

```
{{postItem._embedded['wp:term'][0][0].slug}}
{{postItem._embedded['wp:term'][0][1].slug}}
{{postItem._embedded['wp:term'][0][2].slug}}
{{postItem._embedded['wp:term'][0][3].slug}}
...
```

and Tags:

```
{{postItem._embedded['wp:term'][1][1].slug}}
{{postItem._embedded['wp:term'][1][2].slug}}
...
```

Comment: Is there a documentation on the structure of `wp:term`? Will `categories` always be in `0`, and `tags` in `1`? Will it only contain those two entities? Their documentation is indeed sparse.

Comment: Thanks much!! This was very helpful! works like charm

Answer (score 10):

I think what you want is `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1`

You should also find the direct url at `_links` > `author` > `href`

[image]

Comment: Awesome. If you'll accept the answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: But by this method you have to query twice(2 calls).One for post data and another for author data.

Comment: You would have to. Use the _embed option as suggested above and it'll open a whole new world of better options.